# Customize the spinner in Android is giving space issue

Tags: android, spinner, android-relativelayout, android-spinner

I have customize the background of the spinner. I have removed the background and showing a spinner down arrow beside that. But if the text are not properly aligned. The bigger length text is showing in complete area but for smaller text, there is a gap coming for text and arrow. I have used the below code:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSelectVehins"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="Select Vehicle"
                android:textColor="#F8F1F1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtSelectVehins" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/sp_veh_insrenew"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/dropdownarrow" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The whole alignment i want to put rightly aligned. I have attached the screen shot here:

[image]

Please help me to fix this.

Here is my adapter to the spinner:

```
 editStateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditStateCity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, Constants.stateList);
                  editStateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                  mSpEditState.setAdapter(editStateAdapter);
```

And here is the custom layout for the spinner text:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:textStyle="bold"  
    android:paddingRight="20dip" 
    />
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to set the gravity to right ?

Comment: Tried Gravity right for each component as well as the Relative Layout. Did not work.

Comment: How are you implementing the adapter? You can't use the default spinner item layout if you want to change the text alignment, you will need a custom one.

Comment: I have added the custom layout which i have used on the adapter. You can see the question where i added the code.

Comment: Adding android:gravity="right" in the TextView for both R.layout.spinner_item and R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item should get you the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing the correct thing. I have added android:gravity = right in the Relativelayout and in the text view for R.layout.spinner_item. Also reduce the android:paddingRight="20dip" to 5 dp. And also removed android:layout_alignParentRight="true" from the Relative Layout.

Comment: @ivagarz Please make your comment as Answer so i can select it as Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The views in the spinner are obtained from the adapter, so if you want to change anything on it, including the text alignment, you will need to edit the layout used as a dropdown resource.

So take your `R.layout.spinner_item` and `R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` resources and update them so the TextView they contain has its text aligned to the right.

```
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:textStyle="bold"  
    android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:gravity="right" />
```